# Video fixed within div

Tags: html, css, css-position, fixed, html5-video

I'm trying to make a website with fixed background video. but I want the background video to be inside one div only and above this video I will write something else. I tried this but didn't work :/

HTML Code:

```
<body>
        <div class="header">

            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">
                    <div class="holder span12 text-center">
                        <p><span>somthing</span> here</p>
                        <p id="p1">- this website is designed by bla bla bla -</p>
                    </div> <!--End holder class-->
                </div><!--End row class-->
            </div><!--End container class-->

            <video id="bgvideo" autoplay loop poster="imgs/main_img.jpg">

                    <source src="videos/main.mp4" type="video/mp4">

            </video><!--End video tag-->

        </div> <!--End header-->

        <div class="service">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid text-center">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet, impedit, fugit. Nisi laboriosam rem optio unde. Saepe harum iusto, provident atque similique nulla dolore ad, sint esse asperiores enim eligendi.</p>

                    <p>Laborum magnam dolorem perferendis, ut, aut maxime. Quia dolores, sequi id architecto ea incidunt magni, enim maiores provident suscipit repellat voluptate possimus! Deserunt, quisquam non! Harum a architecto, quas tempora.</p>

                    <p>Ut nemo eligendi consequuntur reprehenderit cupiditate eveniet eos odit ducimus molestiae vitae, maxime ullam, praesentium dolores labore fuga alias eum hic ipsa similique voluptates repellendus. Aliquam facilis, cum fugiat tempora.</p>

                </div><!--End row-->
            </div><!--End container-->
        </div><!--End service-->
</body><!--End body-->
```

CSS Code:

```
.header{
    position: fixed;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#bgvideo{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.holder{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    font-size: 250%;
    line-height: 1;
    margin-top: 300px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: lucidahand;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.service{
   position: absolute;
   top: 1000px;
}
```

---

[Js fiddle of current code.](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/pg4c41xt/)
If you didn't understand me ! this website contain the same idea that I want to make

http://designingmedia.com/html/vizerk/HTML/index-one-video-with-slider-content.html

thanks :D

Comment: When you say "inside one div only" are you referring to it being inside the "header" div along with a bunch of other things (but not also inside any other div) or in its own div?

Comment: exactly, I want it to be inside the header

Answer (score 0):

HTML Code:

```
    <body>

    <div class="header">
        <video id="bgvideo" autoplay loop poster="imgs/main_img.jpg">
            <source src="videos/main.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>

    <div class="sitebody">

        <div class="firstdiv">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <p>bla bla bla</p>
                    <p>bla bla bla</p>
                    <p>bla bla bla</p>

                </div><!-- End row-->
            </div><!-- End container-->
        </div>

        <div class="seconddiv">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <p>bla bla bla</p>
                    <p>bla bla bla</p>
                    <p>bla bla bla</p>

                </div><!-- End row-->
            </div><!-- End container-->

            <div class="thirddiv">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row-fluid">

                    <p>bla bla bla</p>
                    <p>bla bla bla</p>
                    <p>bla bla bla</p>

                </div><!-- End row-->
            </div><!-- End container-->

        </div><!-- End sitebody-->

</body>
```

---

CSS Code:

```
.header{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}

#bgvideo{
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    z-index:-2;
}

.sitebody{/* this class to hold the content so u don't have to set position: absolute for each div or section in your website*/
    position: absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

.firstdiv{
    margin-top: 900px;
    height: 800px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.seconddiv{
    /* write whatever u want */
}

.thirdddiv{
    /* write whatever u want */
}
```

---

Okey, I tried this and worked 4 me , the idea is !! I made fixed header and it's all the time behind your content. so u must set background for each div comes next in your website because if you didn't set a background the video will be shown as background and it's not nice, trust me ☺ ☺

If any one know a better answer please write it down , and if any one can take my answer and make it easier for others I have no problem at all. have a nice day ;)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using Bootstrap, which sometimes can be a d*ck;-) In som situations it's easier to
construct your own div and css. That said, try wrapping your video into it's own container and place it above the text you want to display on top of the video. You then have to set the positions to relative in your css, and then you can place your content on top of your video with the margin set to -xxx px. You will haver to play around a bit to get it centered and apply your won desired responsiveness.

here is how I did it:
(note: when you resize the window the text doesn't stay centered, you have to set your own responsive settings, or maybe when you wrap it in a bootstrap container it will do it for you, although in my experience bootstrap doesn't help you that much when centering containers in containers.

Html:

```
<body>

    <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="bottom-layer">

        <video id="video" preload="auto" src="video/1.mp4"></video>

    </div>

    <div id="top-layer">
        <p>Your Text Here <br />
            Hover me!
        </p>
    </div>


</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#bottom-layer {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    position: relative; /* this */
}
#video {
    margin-bottom: -4px;
}

#top-layer {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: inherit;
    position: relative; /* and this allows you to put the div on top of the video */
    margin-top: -640px;
    /*Hover Off*/
    -o-transition:1.0s;
    -ms-transition:1.0s;
    -moz-transition:1.0s;
    -webkit-transition:1.0s;
    transition:1.0s;
}
#top-layer:hover {
    /*Hover On*/
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.6); 
    -o-transition:1.0s;
    -ms-transition:1.0s;
    -moz-transition:1.0s;
    -webkit-transition:1.0s;
    transition:1.0s;
}
#top-layer p{
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 320px;
}

img,video,canvas {
    width: 100%; /* responsive images,video and canvas elements
}
```

try this and play around with your own desired settings:)

Good luck!

Comment: not exactly, this is not what I meant .. the video is not fixed I want to scroll down while video still in position but when I reach the second div it disappears .. just like that .. copy my answer and see how it works.and improve it if u can .. and yes bootstrap is a dick but still helps in many things :D